# Why %RSD of execution times, while sorting hundreds of arrays, is lower for larger arrays of random integers?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, sorting, quicksort

I am experimenting with the sorting of arrays and their execution times.
While using `bubblesort`, `insertsort` and `quicksort`, I have observed that relative standard deviation (%RSD) of execution times, for five hundred arrays of the same size containing random integers, decreases if the size of the arrays increases.

For example: if the %RSD of execution times while sorting 500 arrays, of size *fifty elements* each, is observed as 7%, the same for arrays with *five hundred elements* each is about 2.5%.

So the question is: why this value of change decreases with the increase in the array size?

**P.S.** I am using a cycle-accurate simulator (gem5) and taking exact clock cycles.

Comment: does the effect persist if you increase your sample size? 500 is not so big and sorting 50 numbers takes a really short time, so random things your computer is doing concurrently can interfere a lot. You should also sort the same array multiple times and take the minimum time to combat these effects.

Comment: @adrianN I am using a cycle-accurate simulator (gem5) and taking exact clock cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `insertsort`, the complexity (time) depends on the number of swaps performed during sorting. A `kth` element `(k=1,2,3,...,n)` in an array of size `n`, may require `0 to k` swappings.

The execution time mentioned in the question depends on the sum of all the swaps performed during the sorting of a complete array.

Considering the random initialization of the arrays, the number of swaps performed for any `kth` element would be a random number bounded by the given range.

Now, If we consider the average value of the number of swaps per element (sum of all the swaps divided by the number of elements in the array), then, according to the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), as the number of elements per array will increase this average will get closer to the expected value.

i.e., the variation in, the total number of swaps per array, among different arrays, will decrease.

Hence, the change (%RSD) in the execution times will also decrease.

--to be continued--